# Changing display symbology in ArcGIS Pro using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, symbology

I am using ArcGIS Pro.

I have a layer created from a shapefile using MakeFeatureLayer. It was then joined with a standalone table. I want to display unique values from the newly joined field. The previous mapping scripts do not work as it has migrated to mp.

How to get this done?

```
arcpy.conversion.TableToTable(folder+r"\Priorigrp.csv", path, "priori")
arcpy.management.MakeFeatureLayer(folder+r"\CountiesBEA.shp", "Counties", '', None, "FID FID VISIBLE NONE;Shape Shape VISIBLE NONE;OBJECTID OBJECTID VISIBLE NONE;FIPS_BEA FIPS_BEA VISIBLE NONE;Shape_Leng Shape_Leng VISIBLE NONE;Shape_Area Shape_Area VISIBLE NONE")
arcpy.management.AddJoin("CountiesBEA", "FIPS_BEA", "priori", "FIPS_CODE", "KEEP_COMMON")
```

This is the part of my code where I get the join. The attribute table looks like:
[image]

I need my tool to directly display the layer with unique value symbology once it's done. However, currently once the tool has worked, I have to manually set the symbology to take the index value and use discrete colors.

Comment: May be you should share your script by editing your question?

Comment: Save your symbology that you have set up as a layerfile, then you can use the apply symbology to layer tool in your script to apply the symbology in the layerfile onto  your new layers.